# Can the camera options on Samsung Galaxy S be imported to Samsung Galaxy SL?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, camera

The Samsung Galaxy S (I9000) and Galaxy SL (I9003) are very similar.. ofcourse, except for a few differences. I use Galaxy SL (I9003). The camera options in Galaxy S seems to have more features than SL. So, can i import those camera options (Shooting mode and Scene mode options) in Galaxy S to my Galaxy SL ?? is something like that possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you're rooted, you may try getting the camera apk from the 9000 onto your 9003, but a safer and easier way would be to use alternate apps from the market. What features precisely are you missing out on in the 9003 from the 9000?

You can try using other camera apps like [Camera Zoom FX](https://market.android.com/details?id=slide.cameraZoom) or [FxCamera](https://market.android.com/details?id=ymst.android.fxcamera).

Loads more in the Market, have a look-see.

Comment: unfortunately, i am not rooted and don't like to root it atleast until i get a good grasp of android OS. As said above, the shooting mode and scene mode in 9000 has some extra options like, action shot, add me, continous, portrait, beach/snow, color of fall, etc.. thought it would be good to have it without installing any apps.. but if the apk replacement won't work, then guess i have no other go! btw, thanks for the apps.. they look cool :) . if no other option works, then i'll go for it.